# How to get most recent 100 data from a Map?

Tags: java, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a Map of Long and String  - Map which stores my timestamp as the key and value as my data.

```
Map<Long, String> eventTimestampHolder = new HashMap<Long, String>();
```

Now I want to get 100 most recent data from the above map by looking at timestamp which is part of key and then keep on adding those data in a List of String. In general populate the 100 most recent data in a List.

What is the best way to do this? Can I use TreeMap here and it will sort my keys basis on the timestamp properly?

In general my timestamp is going to look like this - `1417686422238` and it will be in milliseconds

Comment: A `SortedMap` seems indeed like what you want, and therefore a `TreeMap`.

Comment: Is timeStamp the only part of the key?

Comment: @CBredlow Yes that's the only part of the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you mean by "recent" recently added, then you can try `LinkedHashMap` which will maintain the order of insertion. Then you can iterate over the first 100 items.

You can iterate over the map like this:

```
for(Long key : eventTimestampHolder.keySet()) {
    String value = eventTimestampHolder.get(key);
}
```

Comment: No I didn't mean that, data might come in different order with different timestamp so I need to most recent 100 data so I need to sort it out basis on my key.

Comment: TreeMap does exactly that, it keeps the entries sorted by key.

Comment: So, basically you want the items sorted according to the timestamp which is not the same as most recent 100 items. In this case, `TreeMap` as other people suggested fits your requirement.

Comment: @arynaq got it. Now how can I extract first 100 elements from that map?

Answer (score 0):

For any key that can be sorted, you should use a `SortedMap` (unless there are other requirements making it unsuitable). A `TreeMap` is a sorted map. Since you need the most recent *k* entries, you need the *largest* keys first. This can be done by going through the *k* first keys in the map's `descendingKeySet` as follows, a one-liner in Java-8:

```
eventTimestampHolder.descendingKeySet().stream().limit(k); // in your case, k = 100
```

If you want not just the keys, but the values as well, then you could find the *k*'th key, and then use

```
// the 2nd arg is a boolean indicating whether the k'th entry will be included or not
eventTimestampHolder.tailMap(kthTimestamp, true);
```

One thing to remember when using `tailMap` is that it will be backed by the original `eventTimestampHolder` map, and any changes to that will be reflected in the returned tail map.